# how to get products purchased by customer custom report

Tags: magento2

I created custom report module based on `Ordered Products Report`.

https://github.com/sivajik34/products-by-customer

Present I'm trying to build query like this.

```
SELECT so.customer_id, soi.sku, sum( soi.qty_ordered )
FROM sales_order so
INNER JOIN sales_order_item soi ON soi.order_id = so.entity_id
WHERE  soi.parent_item_id IS NULL
GROUP BY soi.sku order by so.customer_id
```

I need report like this.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I installed your module and tried it. Following are the changes that I made to make it working. My changes will just add new column in your layout to display the emailid of customer

in your view/adminhtml/layout/tonyreports_report_product_sold_grid.xml

update

```
<block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column" as="email">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="header" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Customer Id</argument>
        <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">text</argument>
        <argument name="index" xsi:type="string">customer_id</argument>
        <argument name="id" xsi:type="string">email</argument>
        <argument name="column_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-email</argument>
        <argument name="header_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-email</argument>
    </arguments>
</block>
```

To

```
<block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column" as="custid">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="header" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Customer Id</argument>
        <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">text</argument>
        <argument name="index" xsi:type="string">customer_id</argument>
        <argument name="id" xsi:type="string">custid</argument>
        <argument name="column_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-custid</argument>
        <argument name="header_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-custid</argument>
    </arguments>
</block>
<block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column" as="email">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="header" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Email Id</argument>
        <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">text</argument>
        <argument name="index" xsi:type="string">email</argument>
        <argument name="id" xsi:type="string">email</argument>
        <argument name="column_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-email</argument>
        <argument name="header_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-email</argument>
    </arguments>
</block>
```

and in Model/ResourceModel/Product/Sold/Collection.php

replace function addOrderedQty by following function

```
public function addOrderedQty($from = '', $to = '')
    {
        $connection = $this->getConnection();
        $orderTableAliasName = $connection->quoteIdentifier('order');

        $orderJoinCondition = [
            $orderTableAliasName . '.entity_id = order_items.order_id',
            $connection->quoteInto("{$orderTableAliasName}.state <> ?", \Magento\Sales\Model\Order::STATE_CANCELED),
        ];

        if ($from != '' && $to != '') {
            $fieldName = $orderTableAliasName . '.created_at';
            $orderJoinCondition[] = $this->prepareBetweenSql($fieldName, $from, $to);
        }

        $this->getSelect()->reset()->from(
            ['order_items' => $this->getTable('sales_order_item')],
            ['ordered_qty' => 'SUM(order_items.qty_ordered)', 'order_items_name' => 'order_items.name']
        )->joinInner(
            ['order' => $this->getTable('sales_order')],
            implode(' AND ', $orderJoinCondition),
            'customer_id'
        )->joinInner(
            ['customer' => $this->getTable('customer_entity')],
            'order.customer_id = customer.entity_id',
            ['email']
        )->where(
            'parent_item_id IS NULL'
        )->group(
            'order_items.product_id'
        )->having(
            'SUM(order_items.qty_ordered) > ?',
            0
        )->order('order.customer_id');
        return $this;
    }
```

Attached the screenshot of output.

Hope that helps.

[image]

Comment: Hi, I have used this module, but whenever we try to export report in csv it redirects to dashboard and csv not exported. Can you please help

Comment: I get 404 when i click the new page for admin